Small submodules and projective covers
Let $M_R$ be a module. We say that a submodule $N\subset M$ is small in $M$ (written $N \ll M$) if there is no proper submodule $V$ of $M$ with $M=U+V$ (equivalently, if $M=U+V$, then $V=M$). We say that a projective module $P$ is a projective cover of $M$ if there exists an epimorphism $f:P\to M$ with $\ker f \ll P$.
Let $M$ be a projective module. I need to prove that if $M/U$ has a projective cover, then there exists a summand $V$ of $M$ such that $M=U+V$ and $U \cap V \ll V$.
Attempt: If $M/U$ has a projective cover, then there exists an epimorphism $f:P\to M/U$ with $\ker f \ll P$. Since $M$ is projective, then there exists a homomorphism $g:M\to P$ such that $fg=\pi$ where $\pi:M \to M/U$ is the canonical projection.

Doesn't your definition of a projective cover miss the condition that $P$ is projective? See here. When $P$ is projective, you can probably change your approach.

Oh thanks. It was a mistake. I edited the post.

Wisbauer wrote a proof in his book foundations of module and ring theory in section 42. But I don't understand his proof. @MartinBrandenburg
